# How does having different StackOverflow, CS, and DSP sites help anyone?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, area-51, migration

I've been working a lot with computer vision, in particular OpenCV.  I used to be able to work with just SO, however I'm increasingly having to search across [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930134/entropy-for-a-gray-image-in-opencv), [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10137/spectral-entropy-calculation-in-matlab), and [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10862/shannon-entropy-to-min-entropy) to see if a question has been asked and answered.

This is a pain for me and I don't think it is really helping anyone.  I also feel like it does not follow the [faq on area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) explaining when a new site should be made:

> Should my idea be part of an existing site, or its own site?
>   In general, if a site makes sense as part of a bigger site, it's better to have one big site than a bunch of little niche sites. Site X should be subsumed by site Y if:

1. Almost all X questions are on-topic for site Y
2. If Y already exists, it already has a tag for X, and nobody is complaining
3. You're not creating such a big group that you don't have enough experts to answer all possible questions
4. There's a high probability that users of site Y would enjoy seeing the occasional question about X

It seems to me that based on these statements CS and DSP belong as tags under Math and do not merit their own site.  Computer Science is the study of computation which is 'the action of **mathematical** calculation.' Digital signal processing (DSP) is the **mathematical** manipulation of an information signal to modify or improve it in some way.  Having different sites for different fields of mta

As a user, it would make sense for me to go to Math when I wanted the mathy part of computer vision and SO when I was working with code.

How is the current system better than having DSP and CS under math?

Comment: What exactly is the feature request here? What are you suggesting? From what I was able to understand, it's just a not-so-constructive rant.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Perhaps I mistagged this, my apologies if I did.  I'm trying to understand why DSP and CS were created when I'm thinking they would fit just fine under math. User feedback is ***never*** a not-so-constructive rant...ever.

Comment: To stretch an analogy a bit, SE sites are like academic departments.  You would be more likely to work at an engineering school rather than in a math department if you were a specialist in DSP.  In the 60s and 70s, a lot of "computer science" professors did work in math departments, but both disciplines have evolved to the extent that there's not as much overlap anymore.  A simple dictionary definition of a topic can't possibly be used as a blanket statement for such diverse fields of study.

Comment: 1. Have you read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/160917? 2. *"It seems to me that based on these statements CS and DSP belong as tags under Math and do not merit their own site."* - You have a pretty significant misunderstanding about the scope of CS.SE and Math.SE.  Have you tried posting on Meta.CS.SE?  Have you read prior posts on Meta.CS.SE, e.g., http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/704/755, http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/711/755.  There's *lots* of stuff on CS.SE that would not be welcome on Math.SE -- possibly the majority of questions on CS.SE.

Comment: 3. For computer vision specifically, my experience is that the good stuff is mostly found on Stack Overflow and to some extent on DSP.  While computer vision is on-topic for CS.SE, CS.SE doesn't seem to have a large community of computer vision folks and doesn't attract many answers about computer vision.  Not sure if this will be helpful to you.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for the comment (and especially the links), it has help clear up some misunderstanding about math.se.  I agree with your point #3, although I'm finding that to be less true as time passes.   I'm a bit nervous at the trend I'm seeing--it doesn't matter much when searching, but knowing the rules to ask correctly for different communities can be a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with these particular sites, but assuming they were created for all the right reasons, then it helps you because:

1) If you have a question that's only on-topic on one of those sites, then you might not have been able to ask it if they didn't all exist. But I'm guessing this benefit doesn't apply to you all that much.

2) If you have a question that's on-topic on multiple sites, then **you can choose which audience you want to ask**. I'm sure there are questions for which programmers, computer scientists and signal processing experts will all give good yet different answers.

Here's a not-amazing-but-probably-good-enough example of #2 from sites I do visit:

- SciFi.SE version: [Why did Red Squadron give their call signs in random order?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83209/why-did-red-squadron-give-their-call-signs-in-random-order)
- Aviation.SE version: [Is the "Red two standing by" dialog in Star Wars: A New Hope sensible for real fighter pilots?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13094/is-the-red-two-standing-by-dialog-in-star-wars-a-new-hope-sensible-for-real-f)

---

Also, though this doesn't answer the particular question you asked, it's worth mentioning that [you can search all the SE sites at once from the main site](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=entropy). I find it to be unusably slow, but at least it exists.

Comment: `I'm sure there are questions for which programmers, computer scientists and signal processing experts will all give good yet different answers.`  This is the crux of it, I think.